# How do I resolve .local. DNS names on Debian 10?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, avahi, mdns

I have a small local Ethernet network which I am using as a prototype for an industrial automation network. The network currently has 2 machines, both running Debian 10. There is no DNS server configured on the local network. Instead, the host name and IP address of each machine is included in the `hosts` file the other machine.

I can ping each machine from the other (e.g. `ping machine01` works from machine02, and vice versa).

I now have the need to resolve the machine names in the format `machine01.local.`

I understand that the `.local.` suffix conforms to some [general mDNS standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local), but I am struggling to figure out how to resolve host names in this format - when I try `ping machine01.local.` from machine02, I get the response "Name or service not known".

I have installed `avahi-daemon`, `avahi-discover` and `libnss-mdns` on both machines. `avahi-daemon` is running, but I have not changed the default configuration of this daemon.

The contents of the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is as follows:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

I am obviously missing some basic configuration setting that would allow host names with the `.local.` suffix to be resolved.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your firewalls.